# Django channels working with ws:// but fails to handshake with wss://

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-web-services, websocket, django-channels

### nginx setting

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.sample.co;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    ssl on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name www.sample.co;
    rewrite ^(.*) https://beta.sample.co$1 permanent;
    ssl_certificate /home/ubuntu/certificate/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ubuntu/certificate/private.key;
    root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

### Running on daphne

```
CMD ["daphne","-b","0.0.0.0","-p","8001","config.asgi:application"]
```

### Working fine on

```
ws://xyz.amazonaws.com/ws/sample/<sample-id>/
```

### Fails to work on

```
wss://xyz.amazonaws.com/ws/sample/<sample-id>/
```

### Error:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://xyz.amazonaws.com/ws/sample//' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The applications are running on AWS. The WebSocket is getting called from https. I tried to call the WebSocket with `ws://` from a dummy react app in local it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have CORS policy enable which was restricting to connect to the websocket. After disabling it is working fine for me